# Android Json Parse returns nothing

Tags: java, php, android, json, parsing

I have a Json Parser Class which looks like this:
public class JSONParser {

```
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        JSONArray jObj = new JSONArray(json);
        System.out.println(jObj.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

Near the end at the last try and catch statement I print out the jsonObject as a string I correctly get the data in the console, the json looks like this:

> [{"id":1,"name":"Blooper","description":"Blooper","video_url":"Blooper","platform":1100110011,"logo":"","avaible":0,"token":"","created_at":"2016-04-03
>   17:19:49","updated_at":"2016-04-03
>   17:19:49","release_at":"2016-05-08"},{"id":2,"name":"Blooper","description":"Blooper","video_url":"Blooper","platform":"11000000000","logo":"","avaible":0,"token":"","created_at":"2016-04-03
>   17:26:13","updated_at":"2016-04-03
>   17:26:13","release_at":"2016-05-08"}]

I used a validator and it is fine.

In my AllProducts activity I try to display that inside the android app.

It looks like this:

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.155.27:8000/index";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "id";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "description";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "video_url";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    // getting JSON string from URL

                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);
                    // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                    Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

                    try {
                        // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                        if (success == 1) {
                            // products found
                            // Getting Array of Products
                            products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                            // looping through All Products
                            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                                // Storing each json item in variable
                                String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                                // creating new HashMap
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                                map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                                productsList.add(map);
                            }
                        } else {
                            // no products found
                            // Launch Add New product Activity
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    NewProductActivity.class);
                            // Closing all previous activities
                            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                            TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

If I try to print out this json:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
```

I get no values (null), so my view keeps being empty.

I get follwing error message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                              at
>   com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts$1.run(AllProductsActivity.java:150)

Line 150 is this :

```
Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());
```

Thus Android Studio tells my that

> jObj

here, in my jsonparser:

```
try {
    JSONArray jObj = new JSONArray(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
```

is never used.

> http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

I am not really experienced with this so I really hope for some help, thanks.

Comment: `if(method == "POST"){` -> [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: what do you mean excatly? (the app gets on the get method)

Comment: It works because `String method` apparently is holding hardcoded literal `"POST"`. So since literals are stored in String Pool you are ending up with exact same String instance which `==` confirms. But if you would use String which is not in that pool (like when you created it dynamically - by reading some source: file, socket) and pass it to your method you would see that comparing with `==` would fail which is why comparing using `equals` is preferred.

Comment: so like method.equals("POST")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With  `JSONObject json = new JSONObject();` you are creating an empty `JSONObject`,

the `JSONObject` returned by `jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);` is never used.

You have to do it like this:

`JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);`

so your `JSONObject` from the JParser will be stored in `json`.

Comment: First Thanks for the answer, I changed the code like you told me to do and I get following error message:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: It's because your code looks like 

  `try {
        JSONArray jObj = new JSONArray(json);    
  }
    return jObj;`

the local variable `jObj` is only visible in the try block, you are returning the class varible `jObj` which is never initialized.

Comment: you have to initilize your class `jObj` in the try block. Depending on the json  libary you're using, you have to get an `JSONObject` from your json string

Comment: Hmm ok could you may show me a snippet on how excatly you mean this please

Comment: If you have time I would be willing to have a chat:)

Comment: Hi I could not answer earlier how would you like to have a chat via skype?I only have 18 repuation points on stackoverflow need 20 to chat

Comment: Just post your skype or something similiar and I will contact you

Comment: join this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108211/android-json-parse-returns-nothing @AlexOxilg

Comment: Hi I am online now